# Is sum of expected triangle areas equal to expected area of triangle sums?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, triangles, recreational-mathematics, geometric-probability

### Starting point

Given are 4 multinormal distributions $\mathcal{N}(\vec{\mu}_1,\Sigma), \mathcal{N}(\vec{\mu}_2,\Sigma),\mathcal{N}(\vec{\mu}_3,\Sigma),\mathcal{N}(\vec{\mu}_4,\Sigma)$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$. From every distribution a random point is selected. The expected areas of the 4 triangles that can be formed with the 4 random points are $\mathbb{E}(A_1),\mathbb{E}(A_2),\mathbb{E}(A_3),\mathbb{E}(A_4)$. The expected area of the sum of the 4 triangle areas is $\mathbb{E}(A_1+A_2+A_3+A_4)$.

### Goal

Prove or disprove that $\mathbb{E}(A_1+A_2+A_3+A_4)=\mathbb{E}(A_1)+\mathbb{E}(A_2)+\mathbb{E}(A_3)+\mathbb{E}(A_4)$

### Assumptions

1. the covariance matrix is $\Sigma=\sigma^2\mathbb{\bf{I}}$ (with $\mathbb{\bf{I}}$ the identity matrix in $\mathbb{R^3}$ and $\sigma^2$ the variance)
2. triangle points and distributions have a one-to-one correspondence (i.e. no 2 points are from the same distribution)
3. area is non-oriented

---

The question is intentionally related to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3531811).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true quite generally and is called the [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Basic_properties). It has nothing to do with the particulars of your problem.

Comment: The 4 single triangle areas are not independent as they share points. Therefore I do not see why there is a linearity.

Comment: @granularbastard: Yes, that's precisely the point. If linearity of expectation would only hold in case of independence, it would be far less interesting and useful.

Comment: @granularbastard: If this doesn't seem intuitive: The Wikipedia article doesn't have a proof, but it's easy to find one online; e.g. [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/).

Comment: That's really surprising.

Comment: Could this be proved solely by using $\mathbb{E}(A)$ not knowing the rule of linear expectation? Actually a closed expression for $\mathbb{E}(A)$ is not known and discussed here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/445185

Comment: @granularbastard: I don't know, I haven't looked into that. I guess if a closed form is not known, it will be difficult to prove it using $\mathbb E(A)$.

Comment: So it is strange that something can be proved by general principles without knowing an expression for the special case.

Comment: @granularbastard: Really? Don't we do that all the time? We can prove that the primes are asymptotically distributed in a certain way, even though we're terribly bad at finding even just the very first few of them explicitly (as e.g. measured by the fact that the reciprocals of all known primes add up to about $4$ whereas the sum of the reciprocals of all primes is infinite).

Comment: This is not the same as a closed expression in form of the lmit of a series is known. But there is no expression for $\mathbb{E}(A)$.